# Insert long description into table in TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am now working on table using TableLayout to insert big data(long descriptions) in each column, as shown in the image. Because the description is too long in one column, all the words will misplace all the alignment run and the words cannot goes down the column.Any other way besides using TableLayout? The description in each column will be fetch from database.[image: This is the sample I want to implement in my android project]

Comment: can you show the screenshot of your existing layout

Comment: Hi @VivekMishra updated my code.

Comment: I asked for screenshot though code was also required

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded.

Comment: Just add bit of padding to your table row and follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006899/force-textview-to-mutiline-without-n

Comment: Thanks, will the description at each column goes down instead of going straight when i key in ?

Comment: If it will exceed that Max width it will shift to the next line

Comment: Thanks @VivekMishra it works. Appreciate.

Comment: Also I would suggest to use adapters for this to make your code more dynamic

Comment: Any example or link? And do you know how to add line between the table. because now it doesn't show line.

Comment: you can many examples for using adapters. What you have to do is create your dataset as a list and pass to adapter along with a listview or recyclerview component. For adding line between table simply add a view component after the row and give it 1 dp height and match parent width along with your desired color.

Comment: Thanks. I try to key in the marks, but it cant be total up the final marks from each row. Do you have any tutorial on adding marks from each row and insert into db?

Comment: I have already told you using listview or recyclerview will be best for you for all cases.

Comment: Yes I have take note. There are many tutorial out there and I am not sure which is the best.

Comment: try with androidhive tutorials.